# How to run a test at point using lsp?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I'm using

- https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server
- https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode
- https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/
- https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/servers/

and following this guide:

- https://www.mattduck.com/lsp-python-getting-started.html

One thing I use frequently in python development is elpy's `C-c C-t` to run a single test at point.

How can I configure this to use `lsp-mode` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my Emacs Python environment, I recently switched from `Elpy` to `lsp-mode` too. Mainly to benefit from the `dap-mode` debugger and a better "Find definition" functionality (able to find a definition in the virtual environement libraries). And also because the great `Elpy` package is not maintained anymore.

But what I was still missing from `Elpy`, was the ability to quickly run the tests as @Mittenchops pointed it out.

As I couldn't find any package to easily fix that, I wrote my own `Elisp` functions : `django-run-all-tests`, `django-run-buffer-tests`, and `django-run-test-at-point` (the last one inspired by the Elpy one).

These work well assuming :

- it is a `Django` project (else the test runner command needs to be adapted)
- tests are in a single directory that have to be configured with `django-tests-dir-name` variable relatively to the project root (`(setq django-tests-dir-name "tests")` for example)
- `projectile` package is installed (needed to retrieve project root)

```
;; Copy of elpy-test--current-test-name function from Elpy project
;; https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy
(defun django-get-test-name-at-point ()
  "Return the name of the test at point."
  (let ((name (python-info-current-defun)))
    (if (and name (string-match "\\`\\([^.]+\\.[^.]+\\)\\." name)) (match-string 1 name) name)))

(defun django-get-module ()
  (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-name)))

(defun django-run-tests (&optional module test)
  (let* ((dir-part django-tests-dir-name)
         (module-part (if module (concat "." module) ""))
         (test-part (if test (concat "." test) ""))
         (param (concat dir-part module-part test-part))
         (command (format "./manage.py test %s --keepdb" param)))
    (message command)          
    (projectile-run-async-shell-command-in-root command "*Django tests*")))

(defun django-run-all-tests ()
  "Run all Django api tests."
  (interactive)
  (django-run-tests))

(defun django-run-buffer-tests ()
  "Run Django api tests for current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((module (django-get-module)))
    (django-run-tests module)))

(defun django-run-test-at-point ()
  "Run Django api test at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((module (django-get-module))
        (test (django-get-test-name-at-point)))
    (django-run-tests module test)))
```

Put this code in your `init.el` file. An example using `use-package` package and adding some key bindings to the Python mode :

```
(use-package python
  :bind (:map python-mode-map (("C-c t a" . django-run-all-tests)
                               ("C-c t f" . django-run-buffer-tests)
                               ("C-c t p" . django-run-test-at-point)))
  :config
;; Past the functions here
)
```